# How to use multidimensional dict in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, multidimensional-array, defaultdict

I'm trying to use a multidimensional dict in python. In my case, I need to use a structure like this:

```
MyDict[domain][IPAddress][UserAgent1, UserAgent2, UserAgent3, ....]
```

In this structure each key is a String and the last values are in a vector. I'm using this code for the first insertion:

```
from collections import defaultdict
MyDict= defaultdict(lambda: defaultdict(lambda: defaultdict(3)))

if domain not in MyDict:
    MyDict[domain] = [] 
if IPAddress not in MyDict[domain]:
    MyDict[domain].append(IPAddress)
if UserAgent1 not in MyDict[domain][IPAddress]:
    MyDict[domain][IPAddress].append(UserAgent1)
```

But this code doesn't work for this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/.../Main.py", line 33, in <module>
    if UserAgent1 not in MyDict[domain][IPAddress]:
TypeError: list indices must be integers, not str
```

Additionally, I need to iterate on this structure. Do you know how to implement this structure and the best way to iterate on them?

Comment: fyi, you can shorten your code by using the `setdefault` method all dicts have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you have assigned a list to `MyDict[domain]` rather than a dictionary, try this instead:

```
if domain not in MyDict:
    MyDict[domain] = {}
if IPAddress not in MyDict[domain]:
    MyDict[domain][IPAddress] = []
if UserAgent1 not in MyDict[domain][IPAddress]:
    MyDict[domain][IPAddress].append(UserAgent1)
```

I'm not clear exactly what you want to see in the iteration, but this should get you started:

```
for domain in MyDict:
    for ipAddress in MyDict[domain]:
        for userAgent in MyDict[domain][ipAddress]:
            # code here will run for each combination of domain, ipAddress and userAgent
```

or the more 'Pythonic' version:

```
[[domain, ipAddress, userAgent] for domain in MyDict for ipAddress in MyDict[domain] for userAgent in MyDict[domain][ipAddress]]
```

Comment: Nice answer so far. The second part of OP's question asks how to iterate over `MyDict`.

Comment: Excellent answer. Can you please tell me also how to iterate on this? Thanks

Comment: @hasmet what values do you want to see in the iteration?

Comment: I need to iterate on all values.....I mean, I need a similar solution like 3 nested for:

for domains in MyDict:
   for IPAddresses in MyDict[domain]:
      for UserAgents in MyDict[domain][IPAddress]:
         ...

Comment: @hasmet but do you just want to see the UserAgents or the domains/ips as well and if so what data structure should they be in?

Comment: @codebox: if you don't understant the code (not well formatted in comment box) I can edit the question

Comment: Sorry for the delay codebox. Your solution is exactly what I need. Thank you very much!!